# php constructor not getting called? or something?

Tags: php

When TestPage.php is run in browser, 'trying to create new obj...' is echo'd, but nothing else. Is the constructor not getting called?

This isn't the full code for either class, but hopefully it's enough for someone to tell me where I'm going wrong...

TestPage.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        class MyClass {
        $api_key = 'somestring';
        $username = 'username';
        echo 'trying to create new obj...';
        $myObj = new MyClass($api_key, $username);
        echo 'new obj created...';

    ...
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

MyClass.class.php

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    protected $_api_key;
    protected $_username;


    public function __construct($api_key, $username) {
        echo 'entered constructor...';
        $this->_api_key = $api_key;
        $this->_username = $username;
        echo 'leaving constructor...';
    }

    ...
}
?>
```

Comment: Whenever you're developing, you should be either actively watching your web server's error log (Apache's error log for example) or display_errors should be on.  That way you would see the syntax that is killing your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually define it as a class. That would look like:

```
class MyClass {
    protected $_api_key;
    protected $_username;


    public function __construct($api_key, $username) {
        echo 'entered constructor...';
        $this->_api_key = $api_key;
        $this->_username = $username;
        echo 'leaving constructor...';
    }
}
```

Just placing the code you have in a file and naming it won't do anything on its own.

Additionally, you'll need to include that file if you haven't already. Something like:

```
include 'MyClass.class.php';
```

Comment: Thanks....I did have it in a class, actually, mistakenly edited that out, but I can't believe I forgot to include or require_once the class file. Must be time to go home for the day.

Comment: Happens to everyone from time to time. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You need `class` keyword to define a class please http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php for some basic examples

Try

```
class MyClass
{
 protected $_api_key;
    protected $_username;


    public function __construct($api_key, $username) {
        echo 'entered constructor...';
        $this->_api_key = $api_key;
        $this->_username = $username;
        echo 'leaving constructor...';
    }
}
```